# How to validate PDF content which opened in new window using java script

Tags: javascript

I am opening PDF document in new window by using Java script as like below

```
widow.open("myPDFUrl")
```

How can I detect if Acrobat Reader was successfully opened without lossing its content in the new browser window?

Comment: Are you using any server side language? php? asp.net?

Comment: Why would that tell if the client had Acrobat installed correctly?

Comment: @jcr what do you need to know? There are some client sniffers around....

Comment: I am using jsp. I have to display error message in the main page where i have launch point to PDF, if the pdf is NOT opened properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a javascript code bridge. You can embed your pdf using javascript and then checking if it was loaded succesfully.

See [this page for example](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Passing_information_actions_from_the_browser_to_an-18885.html). Especially the part where you can see the comment line

```
// initialization success
```